# Error Messaging Template

Tags: template

I'm trying to send a message via [whatsapp using the Messaging Template](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.livemessage_automatic_message_notifications_create.htm&type=5) and although the message arrives on my phone, this error is happening in the Messaging Template Error Log:

[image]

Does anyone know why?

Comment: hi mark could you explain how to use the Messaging Template Error Log, for me dont appears nothing